# Equivalent python functions for several matlab image processing functions

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is there an equivalent python function for each of the following (maybe in the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/)??):

edge(image, 'canny')

strel('line',..)

strel('diamond',1)

imdilate(...)

imfil(...)

imerode(...)

medfilt2(...)

All of my simulation code is in python, but not the IC generation! I wanna get my IC generation into python so I don't have to run matlab every time I run a sim.

Thanks,

tylerthemiler

Comment: There are many useful tools on [luispedro](http://luispedro.org). Specifically, [Python Morphology Toolbox](http://luispedro.org/software/pymorph) for image morphing (i.e. erode, dilate, ect) and a lot more functions on that sites other package, [Mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of image processing libraries for Python, though they are spread across a number of packages:

- [scipy.ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html)
- [scikits.image](http://scikits.appspot.com/image)
- [mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas)
- [pymorph](http://luispedro.org/software/pymorph)
- [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html)
- [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Just go through the documentation pages and look for an equivalent to each of the functions you listed. I think you will find edge detection, morphological operations, flood filling, and filtering functions all available in OpenCV (which is by far the most comprehensive)

Note: they are not all compatible with each other (some use NumPy to store the images, others don't).

Comment: Thanks! I found the other ones since I posted this, but I have never seen OpenCV, I will check it out :)

Comment: @tylerthemiler: To be exact, you will want the python-bindings to OpenCV library

Comment: Ok, I found a lot of what I need in pymorph, I will look into the pyhton-bindings if I get stuck using that!

Comment: PIL and OpenCV do not use numpy. All others do (and are therefore compatible with each other).

Answer (score 1):

Reading PIL, it looks like it has a few functions that will be useful for implementing a canny filter. The morphological erode/dilate functions are apparently not available.

This should get you started on implementing your own canny filter. It performs a sobel filter in the vertical and horizontal directions. That gets you about halfway through the algorithm. From there, you will need to iterate (x,y) over (width,height) and suppress non-maximum edges. Wikipedia has a good explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector

```
import ImageFilter

filtHorizontal = [1, 0, -1, 2, 0, -2, 1, 0, -1]
filtVertical   = [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1]

im = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
edgeHorizontal = im.filter((3,3), filtHorizontal)
edgeVertical = im.filter((3,3), filtVertical)
```

Is PIL the preferred image processing toolkit for python? it looks like it could use some contributions

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is. There are a few alternatives though. [Mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas) has some good functions. There is also [BioIMageXD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bioimagexd/) that is specifically for bio-imaging.